# Fetch vertices (at variable depths) reachable from a node

Tags: groovy, graph, gremlin, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3

[Sample graph of what I'm building](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MpgrS.jpg)

I want to fetch all the students connected to a particular school. The students, however, can be present at any depth in the graph (with respect to the school). 
Ideally, I want to filter the students through the incoming-edge (named 'STUDENT' in this case)

Comment: You will definitely find lots of great help here when it comes to Gremlin. It would really help though if you could provide a sample graph snippet so that you can get answers in context.

A sample can be as simple as a bit of Gremlin that just does a series of addV() and addE() steps such as 

g.addV('root').property('data',9).as('root').
  addV('node').property('data',5).as('b').
  addV('node').property('data',2).as('c').
  addV('node').property('data',16).as('j').
  addE('left').from('root').to('b').iterate()

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that only `class` and `student` labels can be found along the path:

```
g.V().has('school','name','Gremlin School').
  repeat(out('class','student')) /* labels refer to edge labels  */
    until(hasLabel('student'))   /* label refers to vertex label */
```